# MBP Pro M1 with macOS Monterey 12.5 waking itself from sleep (hourly)

Tags: sleep-wake, monterey, power-management

I notice the MBP keeps waking itself from sleep during the night (hourly), even though I turned off power nap, TCPalive, etc.

Has anyone figured out why?

I like my devices to actually sleep when I put them in sleep mode.

```
% pmset -g log | grep -e "Wake from" -e "Dark Wake" -e "Entering Sleep"

2022-07-28 00:46:20 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using AC (Charge:100%) 3783 secs 
2022-07-28 01:49:23 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to AOP.OutboxNotEmpty spu_queue_overflow_ep42/ Using AC (Charge:100%) 45 secs   
2022-07-28 01:50:08 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using AC (Charge:100%) 3803 secs 
2022-07-28 02:53:31 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to AOP.OutboxNotEmpty spu_queue_overflow_ep42/ Using AC (Charge:100%) 45 secs   
2022-07-28 02:54:16 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using AC (Charge:100%) 3803 secs 
2022-07-28 03:57:39 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to AOP.OutboxNotEmpty spu_queue_overflow_ep42/ Using AC (Charge:100%) 44 secs   
2022-07-28 03:58:23 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using AC (Charge:100%) 3781 secs 
2022-07-28 05:01:24 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to AOP.OutboxNotEmpty spu_queue_overflow_ep42/ Using AC (Charge:100%) 46 secs   
2022-07-28 05:02:10 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using AC (Charge:100%) 3792 secs 
2022-07-28 06:05:22 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to AOP.OutboxNotEmpty spu_queue_overflow_ep42/ Using AC (Charge:100%) 45 secs   
2022-07-28 06:06:07 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using AC (Charge:100%) 3803 secs 
2022-07-28 07:09:30 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to AOP.OutboxNotEmpty spu_queue_overflow_ep42/ Using AC (Charge:100%) 44 secs   
2022-07-28 07:10:14 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using AC (Charge:100%) 3802 secs 
2022-07-28 08:13:36 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to AOP.OutboxNotEmpty spu_queue_overflow_ep42/ Using AC (Charge:100%) 45 secs   
2022-07-28 08:14:21 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using AC (Charge:100%) 3782 secs 
2022-07-28 09:17:23 +0300 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to AOP.OutboxNotEmpty spu_queue_overflow_ep42/ Using AC (Charge:100%) 46 secs   
2022-07-28 09:18:09 +0300 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using AC (Charge:100%) 2766 secs 
2022-07-28 10:04:15 +0300 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 lid/UserActivity Assertion Using AC (Charge:100%)
```

```
% pmset -g    
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standby              1
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 SleepServices        0
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             0
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                1 (sleep prevented by sharingd, powerd)
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         20
 tcpkeepalive         0
 lowpowermode         0
 womp                 0
```

EDIT: For bookkeeping, there seems to be a thread on this issue here (no solution/answer found to date AFAIK): https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mbp-14-battery-drain-while-sleep.2328914/

Comment: Don't know if it helps since I'm not experiencing this issue, but how about [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252061187)?

Comment: Thanks, I've already performed those actions (see output of `pmset -g`). Also the log entry is slightly different `AOP.OutboxNotEmpty spu_queue_overflow_ep42/`

Comment: I tried the trial version of (SllepAid](https://ohanaware.com/sleepaid/) and that seemed to show what is happening.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to install any software. `pmset` should be sufficient to understand what is happening.

Comment: Since you don't understand what is going on, you might find SleepAid helpful.  Try it!